# XML\Jquery create listings based on user selection

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

Alright, so what I need to try and accomplish is having a static web page that will display information pulled from an XML document and render it to the screen without refreshing. Basic AJAX stuff I guess.

The trick is, as I'm trying to think this through I keep coming into 'logical' barriers mentally.

Objectives:

-Have a chart which displays baseball team names, wins, losses, ties. In my XML doc there is a 'pending' status, so games not completed should not be displayed.**(Need help here)**

-Have a selection list which allows you to select a team which is populated from XML doc. (done)

-Upon selecting a particular team from the aforementioned selection list the page should display in a separate area all of the planned games for that team. Including pending. Basically all of the games associated with that team and the dates (which is included in the XML file). **(Need help here)**

What I have so far:

HTML\JS

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="batty.css" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Little Batty League</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="library.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
   var IE = window.ActiveXObject ? true: false;
   var MOZ = document.implementation.createDocument ? true: false;


   $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "schedule.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
            var select = $('#mySelect');
            $(xml).find('Teams').each(function(){
            var title = $(this).find('Team').text();
        select.append("<option/><option class='ddheader'>"+title+"</option>");
                    });
                    select.children(":first").text("please make a selection").attr("selected",true);
                }
            });
        });
     </script>
   </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init()">
    <!-- container start -->
<div id="container">

        <!-- banner start -->
        <div id="banner">
            <img src="images/mascot.jpg" width="324" height="112" alt="Mascot" />

           <!-- buttons start --> 
            <table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tr>
                <td><div class="menuButton"><a href="index.html">Home</a></div></td>
                <td><div class="menuButton"><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></div></td>
                <td><div class="menuButton"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></div></td>
                <td><div class="menuButton"><a href="about.html">About</a></div></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
           <!-- buttons end -->

        </div>
        <!-- banner end -->

        <!-- content start -->
        <div id="content">
            <br />
            <form>
                <select id="mySelect">
                    <option>please make a selection</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- content end -->

        <!-- footer start -->
        <div id="footer">
            &copy; 2012 Batty League
        </div>
        <!-- footer end -->

    </div>
    <!-- container end -->
</body>
</html>
```

And the XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Schedule season="1">
        <Teams>
            <Team>Bluejays</Team>
        </Teams>

        <Teams>
            <Team>Chickens</Team>
        </Teams>

        <Teams>
            <Team>Lions</Team>
        </Teams>

        <Teams>
            <Team>Pixies</Team>
        </Teams>

        <Teams>
            <Team>Zombies</Team>
        </Teams>

        <Teams>
            <Team>Wombats</Team>
        </Teams>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Chickens</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Bluejays</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-10T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Pending"> 
            <Home_Team>Bluejays </Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Chickens</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-11T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Bluejays</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Lions</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-18T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Lions</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Bluejays</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-19T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Bluejays</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Pixies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-21T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Pixies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Bluejays</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-23T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Bluejays</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Zombies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-25T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Pending"> 
            <Home_Team>Zombies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Bluejays</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-27T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Pending"> 
            <Home_Team>Bluejays</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Wombats</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-28T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Wombats</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Bluejays</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-30T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Chickens</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Lions</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-31T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Lions</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Chickens</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-04T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Chickens</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Pixies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-05T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Pixies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Chickens</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-07T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Chickens</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Zombies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-08T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Zombies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Chickens</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-10T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Lions</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Pixies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-12T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

                <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Pixies </Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Lions</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-14T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Lions</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Zombies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-15T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Zombies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Lions</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-16T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Lions</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Wombats</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-01-23T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Wombats</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Lions</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-24T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Pending"> 
            <Home_Team>Pixies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Zombies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-25T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Pending"> 
            <Home_Team>Zombies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Pixies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-26T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Pixies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Wombats</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-27T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Wombats</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Pixies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-28T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Zombies</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Wombats</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-04T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Wombats</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Zombies</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-05T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Wombats</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Chickens</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-07T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>

        <Game status="Played"> 
            <Home_Team>Chickens</Home_Team>
            <Away_Team>Wombats</Away_Team>
            <Date>2012-02-08T09:00:00</Date>
        </Game>
    </Schedule>
```

Edit: To be more concise:

How would I pull out the information from the XML file using JS and display it on the page in a chart like format?

How would I code the if statement for the selection list where once a particular team was chosen it would populate a different box (not the same one from the paragraph above) with information pertaining to JUST that team?

Comment: scrolling this spot nearly impossible, please clear your code.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? I'm not seeing it, other than asking for tutorials for some arbitrary topic loosely related to jquery and xml.

Comment: As a side-note: Before traversing through xml using jQuery you should parse the xml into a proper xml document object using `http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/` and than wrap it into a jQuery selector. Just using a jQuery wrapper could cause jQuery to miss-interpret some of the nodes. For example: `success: function(xml) {var $xmlDoc = $($.parseXML(xml))...}`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl If the ajax dataType is `xml`, does jquery parse it as an xml document in the same way that jquery parses the `json` datatype into a javascript object? I'm not being sarcastic, it's just something i havent had to figure out before.

Comment: The objectives are what I'm struggling with. Displaying Team names and games (sans pending) on the web page from the XML source and then displaying specifics for the team selected from the select list.

Comment: @KevinB: Very good question. I'm not sure to be honest. I would assume the return object is still a string object containing valid xml formatted data. I would guess you still should parse the xml into an xml document type but I could be completely over cautious and it may not be required at all.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I had to do some manual parsing for IE while doing an app, but they even needed ie6 back then. I will add the code I used in my answer to this question so that you can take a look.

Comment: @KevinB I had to figure it out once, but dont remember exactly, I have added relevent code to my answer the code had to check IE6 as well.

Comment: From the documentation, the xml should be a document if you use the `xml` `dataType` rather than a string.

Comment: @KevinB: +1, I just seen the part in the ajax documentation on converters: `Default: {"* text": window.String, "text html": true, "text json": jQuery.parseJSON, "text xml": jQuery.parseXML}`. In that case it seems not required to call parseXml again :) Very nice catching that part in the documentation there.

Answer (score 1):

You should go on using jQuery selectors:

Eg: Select all games with some Team

```
var teamName = "Bluejays";
$(xml).find('Game > Home_Team:contains(' + teamName + '), Game > Away_Team:contains(' + teamName + )').each(function(){
  var date = $(this).siblings('Date').text();
  var status = $(this).parent().attr('status');
  });
```

There are many ways to traverse your xml, do whatever you like,

In response to xml parsing issues:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../xml/sdf.xml",
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
    success: parseXml
  });
  function  parseXml(xml)
    {
          if ($.browser.msie) {
            var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);
            xml = xmlDoc;
          } ...
```

Comment: jQuery has a parseXML method (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) which should be cross-browser compatible in parsing xml. There should be no need to have a custom parser method for IE. To quote from it: `jQuery.parseXML uses the native parsing function of the browser to create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to jQuery to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and manipulated.`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl The problem was with IE not accepting xml in local machines and when correct headers were not there in ajax response, that was a edge case anyways :)